# Element with recently added class cannot be found by new class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am trying to grab information from an element that was given a class within the same function, but the class is not found:

HTML:

```
<style>
  .class-b { background: red; }
</style>

<div class="class-a">Hello!</div>
<div class="class-a">Hola!</div>
<div class="class-a">Bonjour!</div>

<button class="clicker">Click</button>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var $b = $(".class-b");

$(".clicker").click(function() {
    $(".class-a:first").addClass("class-b");
    console.log($b.html());
});
```

This returns nothing when I should be getting `Hello!` in my `console.log`. So then I thought, maybe the function has not finished yet and the classes haven't rendered and therefore can't be found. So I removed the logging from the function and inserted it into a callback:

```
var $b = $(".class-b");

function c_log() {
  console.log($b.html());
}

$(".clicker").click(function() {
    $(".class-a:first").addClass("class-b");
    c_log();
});
```

But still nothing is returned. Am I overlooking something with the DOM?

Comment: How could $b know that, after being declared, you would add a class named "class-b" to an element? You need to redefine b inside the click event. In a nutshell, $b will not automatically update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$b` are all the elements with the class name of ".class-b" at that moment. Just because you give a new element the class name of ".class-b" doesn't mean `$b` will be updated.

Just reset your `$b`...

```
$(".clicker").click(function() {
    $(".class-a:first").addClass("class-b");
    $b = $('.class-b');
    console.log($b.html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong is that `$b` is defined before `.class-a:first` is given the class `.class-b`, so `$b.html()` is undefined, as there is no element with the `.class-b`. You need to redefine `$b` when you add the class:

```
var $b = $(".class-b");

function c_log() {
  console.log($b.html());
}

$(".clicker").click(function() {
    $(".class-a:first").addClass("class-b");
    $b = $(".class-b");
    c_log();
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLkpyf0u/1/)

Answer (score 2):

When you've wrote:

```
var $b = $(".class-b");
```

It's literally put any *current* `b`'s into the `$b` variable. It doesn't retrospectively check for new additions when you use `$b` later in your code. Put the above line in your `click` callback, which will re-check it each time, and you're golden.